# Regular expression : "is followed by a slash or is the end of the line"

Tags: java, regex

Using Java, I'm trying to write a regular expression that would parse another regular expression. I want to extract the *named groups* from the source regular expression (those represent parameters separated by slashes in an URL). Also, the source string may or may not start and end with a slash.

For example, for both source strings :

`(?<name>john)/(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)`

and

`/(?<name>john)/(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)/`

I'd like a regular expression that would extract those as named groups:

`(?<name>john)` and `(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)`

I tried :

```
(^|.*/)(?<param>\(\?<[^>]+>[^\)]+\))(/.*|$)
```

But this only returns `(?<name>john)` as a group named "param", not `(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)`!!

When I remove the `(/.*|$)` part, both are returned! But I want this ending condition to make sure a param is followed by a slash or is at the end of the line...

Do you have any idea why `(/.*|$)` prevents the second param to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex: -

```
"(?:/|^)(\\(\\?<.*?>.*?\\))(?=/|$)"
```

And use `Matcher@find` method to extract all the matches.

```
String str = "(?<name>john)/***(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)/(?<not>aaa/bbb/?)***";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:/|^)(\\(\\?<.*?>.*?\\))(?=/|$)").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output : -**

```
(?<name>john)
```

The last one is not printed, as it is neither followed by a `slash` nor `end of line`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rohit. The problem is that your regex will match the second param even is the source string is "(?<name>john)/(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)xxxxx". I want a param to match only if a slash follows or if it's the end of the line.

Comment: @electrotype.. So, in that case, do you just want to match the first param? `(?<name>john)`?

Comment: @electrotype.. Updated the Regex for that. You just need to add `[/$]` at the end. So, that the named pattern is matched, only if it is followed by `/` or `$`.

Comment: @electrotype.. And what about - `(?<name>john)/***(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)/(?<not>aaa/bbb/?)***` Do you want to match the 2nd pattern, which is preceded by `***`?

Comment: `(?<name>john)/***(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)/(?<not>aaa/bbb/?)***` : Only the first pattern would be matched!

Comment: In your last example with `[/$]`, both patterns are matched when I try, even with the "***"!

Comment: @electrotype.. Updated again. Added `(?:/|^)` at the starting to match either `/` or `start of line(^)` before the pattern.

Comment: This looks like Javier anwser. But what I'd really like is to understand why *my* solution doesn't work!

Comment: Your latest solution doesn't work with the string `(?<name>john)/***(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)/(?<not>aaa/bbb/?)` (without the ending "***"). The last pattern should be matched.

Comment: @electrotype.. Ah! sorry. Actually it doesn't match because  the starting `/` of last pattern is already matched in the previous pattern. So, it is not matched again, and hence your pattern does not start with `/` or `^`. You can use `look-ahead assertion` rather, which doesn't capture the matched `/` after the pattern. I updated the Regex for that.

Comment: @electrotype.. And I think, that is why your Regex didn't work. Because the starting `slash (/)` of the 2nd pattern is already captured as the ending `slash(/)` of the previous pattern as you have used a `capturing group - (/.*|$)`, and hence it will not be matched again. So, your next pattern is actually matched starting with `(?...)`, and fails to match.

Comment: @electrotype.. You can also use a non-capturing group `(?:/|$)` instead of look-ahead `(?=/|$)`, because it will also not capture the matched `/`

Comment: It works with `(?=/|$)`, thanks. But not with `(?:/|$)` instead, as you say in your last comment. Also, I just realized that I have to read about "capturing groups", I was sure the middle "/" would have been used for both patterns!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful help Rohit!

Comment: Well `(?:/|$)` should certainly work. Because it's a non-capturing group. Are you replacing `(?=/|$)` exactly with it? Please check it again. And yes, regarding your last line, a character once matched in a capture group is not matched again.

Comment: Yep, `(?:/|$)` doesn't work : `(?:/|^)(\\(\\?<.*?>.*?\\))(?:/|$)` only find the first pattern in `(?<name>john)/(?<facet>aaa/bbb/ccc/?)`!

Comment: @electrotype.. Ah! don't know why it is not working. Anyways you can use `look-ahead` though.

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds are you friends: `(?=\/|\n)`

here's a little example of what you need. [EXAMPLE](http://regex101.com/r/qX4mE2)